# Using RDKit to determine "nonring, nonterminal atoms"

Tags: software, cheminformatics

I am a non-chemist using RDKit to determine the number of "nonring, nonterminal atoms" in a molecule.

I can't find anything in the RDKit documentation that helps with "nonterminal". Can it be used for that?

I can using RDKit's `AtomRings` function to identify atoms in rings, but perhaps there is a more direct way?

Comment: Welcome! I'm not 100% sure I know what you mean by "non-terminal" but I guess you mean that an atom has more than one bond. I'd suggest using [SMARTS](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html) - seems like you want something like [*R0!D1]. It's often helpful to use [SMARTSview](https://smartsview.zbh.uni-hamburg.de/smartsview) to test these patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to use [SMARTS](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html) patterns to perform searches. These are something like "regular expression" patterns for molecular graphs.

At a rough guess, your query converts to `[*R0!D1]`:

- `*` matches any atom (i.e., you don't care if it's a carbon or an oxygen)
- `R0` matches an atom in a ring with size 0 (i.e., not a ring atom)
- `D1` matches an atom with explicitly one bond (so `!D1` matches atoms with more than one bond).

It's often helpful to use [SMARTSview](https://smartsview.zbh.uni-hamburg.de/smartsview) to test patterns.

More on RDKit's SMARTS support can be found in the [documentation](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html#smarts-support-and-extensions)